# Manual deployment from CruiseControl

Tags: deployment, cruisecontrol.net

I have CruiseControl.net set up to run MSBuild and NUnit on my web application and then deploy it to a staging server.

Since NUnit doesn't have an Assert.IsNotUgly() method yet I need to look at the site on the staging server before deployment.

What would be great would be to use Cruise Control to handle the deployment from the staging to production servers using FTP. I know that this can be done as part of the build process, but I'd like to have a two step process that would require QA to go into the interface first and manually click a "Deploy to Production" button.

Is this possible/easy with CruiseControl.net?

John

Answer (score 4):

Yes, basically you want two projects the first being the continuous or compile project, that would probably be interval trigger. The second project you would use an empty trigger block on (this means force build only) and this one would only handle the deploy logic.

Comment: You're probably going to want to write the process to deploy to production as an MSBuild task, not in the CruiseControl project file.  MSBuild is a lot more flexible and powerful than CCNet.

Comment: Exactly, I do use MSBuild to deploy. I just meant a seperate project to give users the ability to force the deployment. THat project only calls MSBuild.